# Reading .xdoc Word Document from Inside Zip File?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, docx, zip

*** This is in Python 3.6 ***

Is it possible to read a Word document from inside a .zip file in Python without extracting any of the contents? If not, is it possible to exclusively extract said Word document?

Currently, I am trying the following:

```
import docx2txt
import zipfile

archive = zipfile.ZipFile(dir_path, 'r')
text = archive.read(file_name)
docx2txt.process(text)
```

Which gives me error: `'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'`.
Similarly, when printed text looks like the following:

```
b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x008\x9a\x1eJ\xbd\x01\x00\x00`\t\x00\x00\x13\x00\x08\x02[Content_Types].xml \xa2\x04\x02(\xa0\x00\x02\...
```

I don't know what this is, but trying to decode it the standard way doesn't work either:

```
text.decode(encoding="utf-8")
```

This only gives me: `'utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 15: invalid start byte`.

Alternatively, if I try to decode it without `docx2txt` it gives me a string of what could only be considered gibberish:

```
import io

archive = zipfile.ZipFile(dir_path, 'r')
text = archive.open(file_name, 'r')
text = io.TextIOWrapper(text, encoding='iso-8859-1', newline='')
text = text.read()
```

Results in a string containing a bunch of characters as follows:

```
5g²àðÁYÑ[¶ê©Ü2 Ê]pä²"E¯ÜeA+Ê}p i;p!Hå>8
```

Is there anyway to actually read this .docx file without unzipping it?

Comment: No, you can't read the contents without decompressing it.

Comment: Below the surface, does this mean the zipfile library is just decompressing (extracting) files from inside the .zip file?

Comment: Yes, that's more-or-less correct.